# eliminate whitespaces in pd.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

lets say I have a csv file with lines in following format.

> 89.96.146.2 # Some String Related,To,45.53,11.0

I want to read these lines in to a pandas dataframe and perform some search function based on the IP address(89.96.146.2).

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='#\s+', header=None).set_index(0)
```

This has a white space with IP?. I can only perform the the search function if I split this as `line.split(' ')[0]`. Why my above code do not eliminate that white space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you need to say that there are spaces before the hashtag:

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\s+#\s+', header=None).set_index(0)
```

Comment: How much Time I wasted on this..:(.. Thanks!